# MySQL update column with unrelated table data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables like this  in mysql

```
a.cardnumber (unique)
a.position (numerical 3 digits or null)
a.serial

b.serial (unique)
b.lastused
```

I want to update any rows in "a" where position is above 600 AND "a.serial" is blank with any serial from "b.serial" where "b.lastused" is either null or more than 30 days ago. When the serial is copied into "a.serial" I want to update "b.lastused" with today's date so I know that the relevant "b.serial" has been used today.

There is no relation to the two tables apart from the serial and any serial from b can be used with any cardnumber in a.

I've tried this using my limited knowledge of mysql but I keep getting an error from my mysql desktop program to say I have an error in my query :(

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Can you post sample table data and expected output?

Comment: Can you provide a small data set. One concern I have is that there will be many NULL to NULL values in a.serial and b.serial so you wont be able to have a unique update. This will cause issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming here that you want to use a separate `b.serial` for each row to be updated in `a`. (This isn't specifically stated, but it seems to me to be most likely; please feel free to correct my assumption if it is wrong.)

I setup a small example. It wasn't clear what the datatypes for each of the columns, so I used INT where I wasn't sure. I used DATE datatype (rather than DATETIME) for lastused.

```
CREATE TABLE a (`cardnumber` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, `position` INT, `serial` INT);
CREATE TABLE b (`serial` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, lastused DATE);
INSERT INTO a VALUES ('x0000',555,NULL),('x0001',700,123),('a1111',601,NULL),('a2222',602,NULL);
INSERT INTO b VALUES (100,'2012-07-15'),(101,NULL),(102,'2010-01-01'),(103,NULL),(104,NULL);
SELECT * FROM a;
SELECT * FROM b;
```

Based on the conditions you give, the rows with cardnumbers 'a1111' and 'a2222' should get updated, the other two rows should not (position <= 600, serial already assigned).

Before we run an UPDATE, we want to first run a SELECT that returns the rows to be updated, along with the values that will be assigned. Once we get that, we can convert that to a multi-table UPDATE statement.

```
SELECT a.cardnumber AS `a.cardnumber`
     , a.position   AS `a.position`
     , a.serial     AS `a.serial`
     , b.serial     AS `b.serial`
     , b.lastused   AS `b.lastused`
  FROM (
         SELECT @i := @i + 1 AS i
              , aa.*
           FROM a aa
           JOIN (SELECT @i := 0) ii
          WHERE aa.position > 600   /* assuming `position` is numeric datatype */
            AND aa.serial IS NULL   /* assuming 'blank' represented by NULL    */
          ORDER BY aa.cardnumber
       ) ia
  JOIN (
         SELECT @j := @j + 1 AS j
              , bb.serial
              , bb.lastused
           FROM b bb
           JOIN (SELECT @j := 0) jj
          WHERE bb.lastused IS NULL 
             OR bb.lastused < DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -30 DAY)
          ORDER BY bb.serial
       ) jb
    ON ia.i = jb.j
  JOIN a ON a.cardnumber = ia.cardnumber
  JOIN b ON b.serial = jb.serial
```

To convert that to an UPDATE, replace the `SELECT ... FROM` with `UPDATE`, and add a `SET` clause to assign new values to the tables.

```
UPDATE (
         SELECT @i := @i + 1 AS i
              , aa.*
           FROM a aa
           JOIN (SELECT @i := 0) ii
          WHERE aa.position > 600
            AND aa.serial IS NULL
          ORDER BY aa.cardnumber
       ) ia
  JOIN (
         SELECT @j := @j + 1 AS j
              , bb.serial
              , bb.lastused
           FROM b bb
           JOIN (SELECT @j := 0) jj
          WHERE bb.lastused IS NULL 
             OR bb.lastused < DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -30 DAY)
          ORDER BY bb.serial
       ) jb
    ON ia.i = jb.j 
  JOIN a ON a.cardnumber = ia.cardnumber
  JOIN b ON b.serial = jb.serial
   SET a.serial = b.serial
     , b.lastused = DATE(NOW())

-- 4 row(s) affected
```

You can run the queries for the inline views seperately (ia, jb) to verify that these are getting the rows you want to update.

The join from ia to a, and from jb to b, should be on the primary keys unique key.

The purpose of the ia and jb inline views is to get sequential numbers assigned to those rows so we can match them to each other.

The joins to `a` and `b` are to get back to the row in the original table, which is what we want to update.

(Obviously, some adjustments need to be made if `serial` is not an INT, or `lastused` is a DATETIME rather than a DATE.)

But this is an example of how I would go about doing the UPDATE you want to do (as best I understood it.)

---

**NOTE:** This approach works with MySQL versions that support subqueries. For MySQL 4.0, you would need to run this in steps, storing the results from the "ia" and "jb" inline views (subqueries) into actual tables. Then reference those tables in the query in place of the inline views. The ii and jj subqueries can be removed, and replaced with  separate `SELECT @i := 0, @j := 0` statement prior to the execution of the queries that reference these variables.

Comment: Hi Spencer7593. I can see how this would work but when I try and run it I get a warning to say there's an error in my MySQL query. I have tracked it down to where the sequential numbers are created:"@i := @i + 1 AS i", "JOIN (SELECT @i := 0) ii" etc. If I remove these lines I can run each inline query and they return the expected results, however without getting a sequential number there's nothing to join the two queries on. The db I am running on is quite old and I cannot upgrade it, maybe the function for creating the sequential numbers isn't available? The version on the db is 4.0.22-nt

Comment: I think I've resolved this by using the code from http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/a-need-trick-for-a-row-number-in-a-mysql-recordset-2008-09-13/ and removing " JOIN (SELECT @j := 0) jj" and removing "JOIN (SELECT @i := 0) ii". Thanks for the query! I'll double check and tick for right answer if it does work.

Comment: Removing " JOIN (SELECT @j := 0) jj" and removing "JOIN (SELECT @i := 0) ii" worked for each inline query and they successfully return the correct details with an additional column (i or j) with sequential numbers starting at 1. However when I run the whole SELECT and join up the two queries it gives an error.

Comment: Oh. I've just read that MySQL 4.0 cannot manage subqueries - that's why it's not working when I try and run the full query.

Comment: @3g Telecoms: With MySQL 4.0, to get this approach to work, you will need to make use of actual tables to hold the results from the subqueries, and then rewrite the query to reference the tables in place of the subqueries.

Answer (score 1):

let me know if this works

```
Update table_a
set serial = 
(
    select b.serial from table_b b
    where b.lastused = NULL 
    OR b.lastused < (current date - 30) limit 1
)
where cardnumber in 
(
select a.cardnumber
from table_a a
where a.position > 600
and a.serial = NULL
)

update table_b b
set b.lastused = current date
where b.lastused = NULL 
      OR b.lastused < (current date - 30)
```

Comment: but be careful. The second query updates all records which match the criteria, not the only one which was used to update the first table

Comment: Hi Arunmoezhi, yes I see about the second query. I need to only update the serials used as I might have a batch of 1m serials and I would want to use these in small chunks automatically each day. Is there a way to only update those serials used? Maybe a second query could be run afterwards which gets the serials in table a and then looks them up in table b and updates table b with todays date for any matching serial which has lastused as null or more than 30 days ago?

Comment: I also get an error when I run the first query. I can run each inline query and these return:
Select b.serial from... = 1 serial which hasnt been used
Select a.cardnumber .... = All card numbers which are in position 600+ and don't yet have a serial.

Should these be returning one serial but lots of card numbers?

Comment: I've found out it is because I am using MySQL 4.0 and this does not support subqueries. I can't upgrade to a later version unfortunately :(